# 200 situps in combination with 100 pushups 6 week program?

Tags: push-ups, sit-ups

For those off you that know about the [200 sit up](http://www.twohundredsitups.com/) and [100 push ups](http://hundredpushups.com/) program, would it be a good idea to combine the two programs in one? The program works by dividing the workout into 3 times a week, with a day of rest between each. I'm thinking of doing the following:
Monday, Wed, Fri: Push ups
Tues, Thurs, Sat: Sit ups

going by their plan, I should be able to finish both programs in about 6 weeks.

Is this efficient? Or will one of the program hinder the other?

Comment: Since I do both movements in a semiannual fitness test for my job, I usually combine the two programs for a few weeks twice a year. I think they are efficient for their limited purposes, however agree with Dave that they are not sufficient as a year round training regimen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're totally un- or de-trained, you might run into trouble recovering between sessions. That might happen anyway, particularly if you don't sleep or eat enough. But I bet it'll work fine.

These programs, however, are not well-regarded due to their focus on strengthening one movement while ignoring its opposite. You do a lot of pushing and a lot of ab strengthening, so where is the pulling and back strengthening? Creating muscle imbalances is not generally the best idea.

Comment: +1: Those trainings may sound like a great idea, but a more balanced approach is way better for your body.

Comment: there are also a program for pulling and back strengthening, maybe I could work those in somehow? The only reason why I'm a bit hesitant to do pulling and pushing together is that they might interfere with one another.

Comment: I'm not sure what pulling/back strengthening program you mean. I would recommend a rational strength training program instead of a marketing product like 100 Pushups. I've heard good things about [SimpleFit](http://www.simplefit.org/workout.html), [Never Gymless](http://www.rosstraining.com/nevergymless.html) and [Naked Warrior](http://www.dragondoor.com/b28/) but I haven't tried them myself, so take them with a grain of salt. (I'm assuming you don't have weights or a gym.) Maybe you should describe your situation in another question and ask for program ideas?